# Black screen weak up after suspend POP!_OS 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, suspend, pop-os

I have installed Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS. I have a problem: where i turn on pc from its suspend, it give me a black screen. I use **GTX 960 + PENTIUM GOLD G4500**. Is it a problem of nvidia driver? I don't want to install open source driver of ubuntu/linux. Can someone help me?
***GTX 960 driver version: 460.67***

```
NAME="Pop!_OS"

VERSION="20.04 LTS"

ID=pop

ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"

PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS"

VERSION_ID="20.04"

HOME_URL="https://pop.system76.com"

SUPPORT_URL="https://support.system76.com"

BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues"

PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://system76.com/privacy"

VERSION_CODENAME=focal

UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

LOGO=distributor-logo-pop-os
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

Check the Bios for updates and ensure that the Nvidia 460 prop drivers support your kernel

Perhaps check that all drives report a clean smartctl self-test

Ensure that your Swap partition is larger than the installed memory.

Find the UUID of your swap partition and add it to /etc/default/grub as the value for resume=

You can also check what ACPI power features the kernel supports:

`cat /sys/power/mem_sleep`

`cat /sys/power/state`

Check this [Intel Wiki on the Linux Kernel Sleep States](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html) after executing both commands.  Its easy to understand.

Comment: Also, switch to the Nuveau drivers in the Updates app if available under Additional Drivers.  My screen had artifacts but it was just for testing anyhow.  Then create a new profile and use the systemd suspend command or suspend button to see how it goes .  That helped me narrow it down.  Ultimately I believe my Core2Quad Mobo didn't support the Linux S3 suspend to ram for Ubuntu 20.04. ‍♂️